# Flutter list iteration error - list function can't be assigned to widget

Tags: flutter, dart, iteration

Am trying to simply print some data from an array but I keep getting an error that say list function can't be assigned to type widget but I've checked everything and each component looks like it should be okay, so let's start with data:

```
class GameOptions {
  String name;
  int key;
  int hidden;
  int random;

  GameOptions({this.name, this.key, this.hidden, this.random});
}
// Populate the Data

List <GameOptions> options = [
  GameOptions(name : "Town Hall",  key : 001, hidden:1, random: 0),
  GameOptions(name : "Chapel", key : 003, hidden:1, random: 0),
  GameOptions(name : "Tavern", key : 002, hidden:1, random: 0),
  GameOptions(name : "Merchant", key : 004, hidden:1, random: 0),
] ;
```

And then the code where I'm calling this data up for a text print:

```
            Expanded(
              flex:3,
              child: Column (
                children: options.map((name) => Text(name)).toList,
              ),
            ),
```

It's the children line where I get the error. Thanks in advance, I can't fathom if it's simple mis-understanding of syntax or if there is a problem in building my List.

Comment: `map` is not the method you're looking for to return a list of text widgets. use .`forEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are passing the whole GameOptions object to the text widget rather than passing its name property over there:

```
 children: options.map((name) => Text(name)).toList,
```

Instead it should be like this

```
 children: options.map((gameOption) => Text(gameOption.name)).toList,
```

Just replace this single line and your code will work perfectly.